# Delete part of string if string contains sub-string in single column instance

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have the following in a pandas DF of message A and B:

```
Message_A
"(Live Storage: 20.00   included in Plan for $15.00 - Exceess of 10.0   @ $6.0)" 
"(Live Storage: 5.00   included in Plan for $5.00 - Exceess of 11.0   @ $40.0)" 
"(Live Storage: 10.0   out of 150.00   included in Plan for $10.00)" 
"(Live Storage: 146.0   out of 200.00   included in Plan for $150.00)" 
"(Live Storage: 150.0   - Tier 1501 to 2000   @ $350)" 
"(PY Solution -Flat Fee- of $30.00 applied)" 
"(Live Storage: 17.0   out of 40.00   included in Plan for $20.00)" 
"(Live Storage: 67.0   @ $5.00)" 
"(Live Storage: 5.00   included in Plan for $55.00 - Exceess of 13.0   @ $6.0)" 
"(Live Storage: 741.0   @ $3.00)" 
"(Live Storage: 30.00   included in Plan for $150.00 - Exceess of 39.0   @ $6.0)" 
"(Live Storage: 65.0   - Tier 51 to 75   @ $250)" 
"(Live Storage: 567.0   - Tier 501 to 750   @ $1750)" 

Message_B
"(! Price for Live Storage not found in Pricing Plan !)" 
"(! Price for Live Storage not found in Pricing Plan !) ( ABC Storage: 141.0   @ $2.00) (Discount of 10.0% applied to storage amount)" 
"(! Price for Live Storage not found in Pricing Plan !)" 
"(! Price for Live Storage not found in Pricing Plan !) ( ABC Storage: 1.0   @ $3.00)" 
"( ABC Storage: 137.0   - Tier 1251 to 150   @ $100) (!  ABC Storage Limit of 00   Exceeded !) (Local Allocated Storage: 20.00   @ $0.40) (Live Storage: 16.0   @ $??)" 
"(Discount of 10.0% applied to storage amount) (! Price for Live Storage not found in Pricing Plan !)"
"(! Live Storage not found in Pricing Plan !) (Discount of 10.0% applied to storage amount)" 
"(! Price for Live Storage not found in Pricing Plan !) (Local Allocated Storage: 100.00   @ $0.50)" 
"(! Price for Storage not found in Pricing Plan !) (Live Storage: 18.0   @ $??)" 
"(! Price for Storage not found in Pricing Plan !)(Live Storage: 69.0   @ $??)  ( ABC Storage: 401.0   @ $1.50)" 
"(Live Storage: 6.0   @ $??) (! Price for Storage not found in Pricing Plan !)" 
"(! Price for Live Storage not found in Pricing Plan !) (Discount of 10.0% applied to storage amount)" 
"(! Price for Live Storage not found in Pricing Plan !) ( ABC Storage: 270.0   - Tier 201 to 300   @ $400)"
```

I am looking to remove the error messages from message_B. These are messages where some of the text changes, but all error messages contain a '!' or '?$$' in them. I then want to join to message_A for a single column message.
For clarity, the middle step looks like:

```
Message_B
Nan
"( ABC Storage: 141.0   @ $2.00) (Discount of 10.0% applied to storage amount)" 
Nan
"( ABC Storage: 1.0   @ $3.00)" 
"( ABC Storage: 137.0   - Tier 1251 to 150   @ $100)(Local Allocated Storage: 20.00   @ $0.40)" 
"(Discount of 10.0% applied to storage amount)" 
"(Discount of 10.0% applied to storage amount)" 
 "(Local Allocated Storage: 100.00   @ $0.50)" 
Nan
"( ABC Storage: 401.0   @ $1.50)" 
Nan
"(Discount of 10.0% applied to storage amount)" 
"( ABC Storage: 270.0   - Tier 201 to 300   @ $400)"
```

With the final result just been a single column string (drop Nan).
I have been able to split message_B by dropping the '(' and .replace ')' with '|' to give a separator to split on.
I have split message_B into a (new) different dataframe, but how do I iterate over the **full** DF and delete the unwanted messages? (I do not want to drop full rows)
I have tried `df[df['Message_B'].str.contains("(Live Storage: 18.0   @ $??)")==False]` But I need to do this for each type of message and the figure within the message changes.
Also, I now realize that I cant use `.str.contains` over a full DF.
Any help would be appreciated, and sorry for how I set out the DF in the message, found it was the easiest for readability. Thanks

**EDIT**
I have been able to take out the standard error message with:

```
error_msg1 = "(! Price for live Storage not found in Pricing Plan !)" 
replace_with = ''
bumi_output['Message_B'] = [i.replace(error_msg1, replace_with) for i in bumi_output['Message_B']]
```

Is there a way to use this method to take out the error messages where a section of the messge can change?? for example:
    (Live Storage: 18.0   @ $??)
    (Live Storage: 69.0   @ $??)

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to include the `snippets`, you can make things into code blocks by indenting each line (4 spaces).  Or while you're writing, if you select the block and hit the `{}` symbol in the editor.

Comment: Thank you @DilithiumMatrix, I had something similar done, using {}, but I didn't have the rows on different lines. I had ',' separator which made it look long and hard to read. I'm not seen much interest, so I could be out of luck with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rather ugly list comprehension gets you what you want from message B by simply finding all the parentheses and excluding the ones with '!' and '$??' and then joining the remaining parts together

```
new_B = [' '.join([subs for subs in re.findall('\(.+?\)', val) if '!' not in subs and '$??' not in subs]) 
for val in df['Message_B']]
```

Then just add this to A

```
df['Message_A'] = df['Message_A'] + new_B
```

To see that this has worked:

```
In [26]: df['Message_A'][1]
Out[26]: '(Live Storage: 5.00   included in Plan for $5.00 - Exceess of 11.0   @ $40.0)( ABC Storage: 141.0   @ $2.00) (Discount of 10.0% applied to storage amount)'
```

Comment: Hi @Woody Pride, I have been trying to get your answer to work but it is probably something on my side. If I follow the logic, your splitting on '(' and ')', then returning anything that doesn't have '!' or '$??'.? For clarity, I am reading the df in with pandas read_csv (including header = 0, names = [x,y,z]). I have also set 'Message 3' to string with '.astype(str)'. When I run your answer, it does run (with no error) but I get no difference. I also don't get the New_B column. I have tried to figure out the problem as I am trying to learn as much as possible, but with little joy :(

Comment: Hi @Woody, I have accepted your answer. I realized I was making a basic mistake. Thank you very much.